# Select multiple rows from one table with a count of another

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble with a select statement. What I have so far is this -

```
SELECT COUNT(booked.desk_id), 
  name, 
  desk.desk_id, 
  phone, 
  fax, 
  dock, 
  pc 
FROM desk, booked 
WHERE desk.desk_id = booked.desk_id 
  AND booking_id >=1 
  AND location = "Cheltenham"
```

Which outputs

```
"12" "Desk 1" "1" "1" "0" "0" "1"
```

Which is close to what I want, but there is another desk in the desk table called Desk 2, which is it completely ignoring. And indeed, if there are bookings for Desk 2 it includes their count in what it is showing as a count for Desk 1...

Entire table strucutres is as follows:

```
table "booked"
INSERT INTO `booked` (`id`, `booking_id`, `desk_id`, `member_id`, `date_booked`) VALUES
(246, 1358121601, 1, 1, 'Monday 14th January at 4:40pm'),
(247, 1358121602, 1, 1, 'Monday 14th January at 4:40pm'),
(248, 1358121604, 1, 1, 'Monday 14th January at 4:40pm'),
(249, 1358121603, 1, 1, 'Monday 14th January at 4:40pm'),
(250, 1358121606, 1, 1, 'Monday 14th January at 4:40pm'),
(251, 1358121605, 1, 1, 'Monday 14th January at 4:40pm'),
(252, 1358121607, 2, 1, 'Monday 14th January at 4:40pm'),
(253, 1358121609, 2, 1, 'Monday 14th January at 4:40pm'),
(254, 1358121608, 2, 1, 'Monday 14th January at 4:40pm'),
(255, 1358121610, 2, 1, 'Monday 14th January at 4:40pm'),
(256, 1358121612, 2, 1, 'Monday 14th January at 4:40pm'),
(257, 1358121611, 2, 1, 'Monday 14th January at 4:40pm');

table "desk"
INSERT INTO `desk` (`location`, `desk_id`, `name`, `phone`, `fax`, `dock`, `pc`) VALUES
('Cheltenham', 1, 'Desk 1', 1, 0, 0, 1),
('Cheltenham', 2, 'Desk 2', 1, 1, 0, 1);
```

What I need help with is how to correctly structure the statement so it will output individual rows for each desk with it's relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `GROUP BY` to go along with your aggregate function:

```
SELECT COUNT(booked.desk_id), 
  name, 
  desk.desk_id, 
  phone, 
  fax, 
  dock, 
  pc 
FROM desk
INNER JOIN booked 
    ON desk.desk_id = booked.desk_id 
WHERE booking_id >=1 
  AND location = "Cheltenham"
GROUP BY name;
```

In MySQL you do not have to `GROUP BY` all fields in the select list, but in other RDBMS you would have to use:

```
SELECT COUNT(booked.desk_id), 
  name, 
  desk.desk_id, 
  phone, 
  fax, 
  dock, 
  pc 
FROM desk
INNER JOIN booked 
    ON desk.desk_id = booked.desk_id 
WHERE booking_id >=1 
  AND location = "Cheltenham"
GROUP BY name, desk.desk_id, phone, fax, dock, pc
```

Based on your sample data and comment, you can use:

```
SELECT coalesce(CountDesk, 0) Total, 
  name, 
  d.desk_id, 
  phone, 
  fax, 
  dock, 
  pc 
FROM desk d
LEFT JOIN
(
  select COUNT(booked.desk_id) CountDesk,
    desk_id
  from booked 
  WHERE booking_id >=1 
  GROUP BY desk_id
) b
    ON d.desk_id = b.desk_id 
WHERE location = "Cheltenham"
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71000/17)

If you want to do this without the subquery:

```
SELECT 
  Coalesce(count(b.desk_id), 0) Total, 
  name, 
  d.desk_id, 
  phone, 
  fax, 
  dock, 
  pc 
FROM desk d
LEFT JOIN booked b
  ON d.desk_id = b.desk_id 
WHERE booking_id >=1 
  AND location = "Cheltenham"
GROUP BY name, d.desk_id, phone, fax, dock, pc ;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71000/22)

Comment: Hi the above looks great, but if the count of booked.desk_ids = 0 then it doesn't output the row. I need it to say 0 if there are none booked... Any ideas?

Comment: Looks beautiful, mate. Works perfectly. Is that the most simple way of doing it though? Crazy long query, lol.

Comment: @Steve see my edit, I updated to use a version without a subquery